# Загрузка .NET runtime в приложение на C++: проблема с mscorlib.tlh

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

Пытаюсь собрать следующий код в Visual Studio 2022, появляются ошибки(скрин ниже) в файле mscorlib.tlh. Как исправить?

```
#include <metahost.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")

#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only \
    high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref") \
    rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    char c;
    wprintf(L"Press enter to load the .net runtime...");
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    HRESULT hr;
    ICLRMetaHost* pMetaHost = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo* pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeHost* pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;

    // build runtime
    hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
    hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));

    // start runtime
    hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();

    wprintf(L".Net runtime is loaded. Press any key to exit...");
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]